# ¿Cómo se utiliza la 'Nueva gramática. Morfología y sintaxis' de la RAE en linea?

Tags: gramática, rae, recursos

Quiero indagar unos asuntos gramaticales y los he buscado en la '[Nueva Gramática, Manual](https://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/gramatica/nueva-gramatica-manual)" de la RAE.  Aunque me han ayudado las entradas en ese libro, quería ver si hay explicaciones más extensas en "[Nueva gramática. Morfología y sintaxis](https://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/gramatica/nueva-gramatica-morfologia-y-sintaxis)" de la misma organización.  Esos libros son bastante caros, pero parece que hay una versión en línea aquí: http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi .   Aunque se me dan bien cosas de la informática, no me parece especialmente fácil usar este servicio.  Específicamente, quiero usarlo como el libro, es decir, buscar en algún tipo de indice por términos, por ejemplo, 'participios con ser y estar'.  Es posible hacerlo en mi libro físico, pero cuando ingreso las claves 'participio ser estar' no se produce ningún resultado.  Si pongo la palabra 'participio' sola, se me da un chorro de resultados; y si selecciona el botón 'lema' a la izquierda antes de buscar, aun así se selecciona 'todos' automáticamente, y recibo cada mención de 'participio' en la obra, es decir, el chorro otra vez.

- ¿Hay un indice accesible?
- ¿Es posible buscar una entrada específica? Es decir, para
  poder buscar una entrada específica que corresponda a la misma
  entrada en el Manual.
- ¿Cómo se realiza lo que quiero hacer?

¿Ha tenido alguien éxito usando esta obra en linea?  Y, por cierto, ¿SON más extensas las entradas que las en el Manual?

Comment: Sí, la versión en línea es muy incómoda de utilizar. No se puede ni siquiera ir a un artículo específico introduciendo su número. No sé si lo hacen a propósito para que la gente compre el libro...